# Why do I have a slow initial response using by the Active Directory server?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, active-directory

Connecting to a named Active Directory server in the  DMZ (i.e. not in the domain), over port 636 using `DirectoryEntry` then pulling attributes using `DirectorySearcher`.

String

```
string serverPath = "LDAP://some.domain.com:636/OU=XXXX,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxxxxxxx";
var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(
serverPath, 
User, 
Pass, 
AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

The first query is very slow, around 22-25 seconds. It was explained to me that this may because IIS 7.5 may be doing a look up of the certificate on the AD server against a CRL, but not getting a response. Then, subsequent queries accept that answer until the process times out, so that the next query will again take 22-25 seconds.

Is the type of connection that I've described in my code example actually pull the certificate, or is the traffic simply sent over the port in an encrypted state, without a handshake between servers relative to the cert?

Is it mandatory that I IIS have a certificate as well for this to work? I should say that I am using  this pattern: http://forums.asp.net/p/907421/1007517.aspx.

Comment: Have you seen this posting: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t768204-directoryentry-nativeobject-slow-with-asp-net-but-fast-in-exe.html

Comment: No thanks, I just went through it. Very similar case, but unfortunately the suggestion in that thread didn't work.

Comment: Worth a shot. I don't have an answer for you, unfortunately, but thought it may be worth posting in the event it was a solution or perhaps someone else has an issue and that post was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

SSL isn't involved here.

What's `serverPath` look like? You probably are timing out on something - DNS perhaps. I'd start with a network trace.

Comment: Just added the serverPath to code example. Wouldn't a trace just show the server as being available/not available?

Comment: Are you in the domain? You shouldn't need the left part (server:port) if you're running in a domain security context. A network trace will very likely show you where the slowdown is occurring.

Comment: Updated the question, server is not in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

When you use port 636, LDAP over SSL is used,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldap

If you use Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark to capture the packets, you may gain more insights on packet level.

In this case, CRL is necessary as it is enabled by default. But you can turn it off on machine or application level,

http://www.page-house.com/blog/2009/04/how-to-disable-crl-checking.html